# ROWVERSION based optimistic concurrency with MERGE statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple `MERGE` statement that I'd like to add optimistic concurrency to.

```
DECLARE @Id         INT,
        @IsEnabled  BIT,
        @RowVersion ROWVERSION;

MERGE [dbo].Subscription WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS [Target]
USING
( SELECT @Id, @IsEnabled )
AS [Source]
( Id, IsEnabled )
ON
( [Target].Id = [Source].Id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET IsEnabled = [Source].IsEnabled
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( IsEnabled ) VALUES ( [Source].IsEnabled );

IF @Id IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @Id = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);
END;

SELECT @Id AS Id;
```

We use [`ROWVERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) to provide the change tracking.

When the RowVersion values don't match then no changes should take place, and we should return a flag indicating that the concurrency check failed so the user can be asked to try again.

I found one [suggested approach](https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/06/18/SQL-Server-2008---MERGE-and-optimistic-concurrency.aspx) which performs an `UPDATE`, setting a column to it's existing value when it detects different [`ROWVERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql)s. This satisfies `MERGE`s desire to have at least on column updated, without actually changing the value.

```
DECLARE @Id         INT,
        @IsEnabled  BIT,
        @RowVersion ROWVERSION;

DECLARE @Result TABLE (WasChanged BIT, Id INT);

MERGE [dbo].Subscription WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS [Target]
USING
( SELECT @Id, @IsEnabled, @RowVersion )
AS [Source]
( Id, IsEnabled, RowVersion )
ON
( [Target].Id = [Source].Id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET IsEnabled = CASE WHEN [Source].Rowversion = [Target].Rowversion          
                                THEN [Source].IsEnabled ELSE [Target].IsEnabled
                           END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( IsEnabled ) VALUES ( [Source].IsEnabled )
OUTPUT  CASE WHEN [Source].[Rowversion] = INSERTED.[Rowversion]
            THEN 0 ELSE 1
        END AS ConcurrencyCheckFailed, INSERTED.Id AS Id
INTO    @Result;

SELECT ConcurrencyCheckFailed, Id FROM @Result;
```

This does initially appear to be an okay workaround, but performing an `UPDATE`, even one that doesn't actually change any values, would still cause that row's [`ROWVERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) to be incremented for no good reason.

That changing of the [`ROWVERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) can lead to failed concurrency checks, and so the user having to retry. And since the change was for no good reason, those failures are very undesirable.

Am I taking the wrong approach trying to get `MERGE` to work how I want?

Or, is there a nifty way to use `MERGE` with [`ROWVERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) based optimistic concurrency?

The more I look at the MERGE statement, the more I think it's simply the wrong tool for this task. It doesn't seem to have any support for this way of working, and the solutions I find online are partially working workarounds rather than proper approaches.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to happen when the ID matches but the rowversion value does not. If you look at the documentation, you can add conditions to the "when matched" clause - and it seems you simply need to add the rowversion check there. In this case, the merge will update nothing.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. When the Ids match but the RowVersions don't, I want to leave the rows untouched and return a flag saying that there was a concurrency violation. `@WasChanged = 0`. "WasChanged" isn't a very good name at all, I should change it. You can have up to two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses, the first having a condition, and the second being matched if the first is not. Also one must contain an `UPDATE`, and the other a `DELETE`. The more I think about it the more `MERGE` seems unsuited to the job. I'll update this question tomorrow to clarify the points you raised. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking to solve this problem, you can replace:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET IsEnabled = CASE WHEN [Source].Rowversion = [Target].Rowversion          
                            THEN [Source].IsEnabled ELSE [Target].IsEnabled
                       END
```

With

```
WHEN MATCHED AND [Target].Rowversion = [target.Rowversion] THEN
UPDATE SET IsEnabled = [Source].IsEnabled
```

This should have exactly the same result result as the original query, with the added benefit that RowVersion will not be touched by the update statement.

The extra AND condition will make sure the WHEN is not executed if the Rowversion does not match, but the WHEN NOT MATCHED will not trigger either.
The result is neither an update nor an insert. And the @Result table variable will remain empty.